# parsing tables with img tags in python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse an html page. I need to work on the first table in the page. That table contains a few rows. Each row then contains some 'td' tags and one of the 'td' tags has an 'img' tag. I want to get all the information in that table. But if I print that table I don't get any data related to the 'img' tag.

I am using soap.findAll("table") to get all the tables then chose the first table for processing. The html looks something like this:

```
<table id="abc"
  <tr class="listitem-even">
    <td class="listitem-even">
      <table border = "0"> <tr> <td class="gridcell">
               <img id="img_id" title="img_title" src="img_src" alt="img_alt" /> </td> </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="listitem-even"
      <span>some_other_information</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get all the data in the table including the 'img' tag ?
Thanks,

Comment: `soup.find('table')` will give you the first table; no need to find them all if you only need the first.

Comment: And you can use `.find` and `.find_all()` on any BeautifulSoup element; `table.find('img')` would give you the image too. What information were you expecting to extract, exactly?

Comment: Thanks for these tips, can I used td.find('img') or something like that ? I want to find out what is the src tag and to what 'td' it is associated with.

Comment: I actually need to read the title of the 'img' tag, and then I've to decide based on that title if the corresponding 'td' is of value to me.

Comment: soup.findall('img') gives me all the images but table = soup.find('table') and then table.findall('img') gives me "None"
any ideas ?

Comment: Are you certain you have a table with an image in the latter part? Verify that by printing `table`.

Comment: The image tag is not displayed when I print the table. But the table in the page that I am parsing contains the image, and I've verified that its the exact same table that it is in the page that gets printed. The only issue is that it doesn't print the image.

Comment: How did you verify that the image is there? In the developer tools of your browser? Take into account that JavaScript and AJAX can alter the contents of a page after loading. Loading a page into Python will not run the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 3):

You have a nested table, so you need to check where you are in the tree, prior to parsing tr/td/img tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open('test.html', 'rb')
html = f.read()
f.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

tables = soup.find_all('table')

for table in tables:
     if table.find_parent("table") is not None:
         for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
                 for td in table.find_all('td'):
                         for img in td.find_all('img'):
                                 print img['id']
                                 print img['src']
                                 print img['title']
                                 print img['alt']
```

It returns the following based on your example:

```
img_id
img_src
img_title
img_alt
```